# Meaning of “méli-mélo”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

At the January page of "calendrier mathématique 2015", it says "Pourquoi le résultant n'est-il pas un méli-mélo terne et flou?"

The janvier's theme is rainbow. So I thought the meaning might be "Why the result of light ray refraction is a clear rainbow, not a mixed-jumbled dull gray and blurred haziness?" According to the Wikipédia, méli-mélo is a title of a film which I've never seen.  And I'm not sure about the translation "mixed-jumbled".

Comment: A generous Frenchman, who I'm following via twitter, taught me:
mélange, fouillis... Familièrement, un "bordel"...
What a quick solution!

Comment: I found the entry http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9li-m%C3%A9lo. I will use Wiktionnaire as well as Wikipédia.

Answer (score 7):

**Méli-mélo** variation vocalique de mêler qui a aussi donné *pêle-mêle*.

Terme familier : Mélange très confus et désordonné.

> Quel *méli-mélo*, une chatte n'y retrouverait pas ses petits.

Par rapport aux synonymes *capharnaüm, confusion, embrouillamini, fouillis, gâchis*,  j'utilise *méli-mélo* lorsqu’il y a de la légèreté dans ce désordre, qu'il est sans gravité.

C'est aussi le nom d'une salade composée.

C'est un terme familier, mais tout à fait correct que l'on peut employer dans un langage soutenu, contrairement à *bordel* : synonymes : *boxon, claque, lupanar* pour le sens original, de *foutoir, pagaille* pour celui de l'organisation et de *boucan, raffut* lorsqu'il s'agit du bruit.

<sup>Références extraites du Petit Robert</sup>

Comment: Rien à faire avec la question, mais l’alternance « /i/o/ » en « méli-mélo » me fait penser bêtement à la chanson « Bali Balo (est un salaud) » !

Comment: @PapaPoule thanks for the interesting comment. And thanks to cl-r. I hope I can use Petit Robert someday :-)

Comment: @noel_lapin Selon mon expérience, c'est le dictionnaire qui permet le plus facilement de connaître les nuances de la francophonie, tout en restant très simple et complet.